# No env variables in bash after exported with command in docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, serverless-framework

I have a serverless.yml file, that defines environment variables. In order to use the ones for my local stage in a docker container I use the [serverless dotenv plugin](https://github.com/Jimdo/serverless-dotenv) in order to export them to an .env file. I do this in my docker-compose.yml where I also export the variables from this file. It works as my django settings have access to them.

```
command: >
  bash -c "sls dotenv -s local
  && export $$(grep -v '^#' .serverless/.env | xargs -d '\n')
  && python manage.py makemigrations ingredients"
```

However, if I bash into the container or run a command, the environment variables are not available anymore:

```
docker-compose exec name python manage.py createsuperuser
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So, `.yml` or `.env`?

Comment: from .yml to .env, where the .env is loaded in the docker command

Comment: What is that story about yml then for? Remove unnecessary information from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of George Appleton, I have added the export command I am already using to the `.bashrc` with the following command for the docker-compose.yml:

```
echo 'export $$(grep -v \"^#\" .serverless/.env | xargs -d \"\n\")' > /root/.bashrc
```

If I now exec bash all environment variables are available.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, a warning though. .bashrc is only read by a shell that's both interactive and non-login. .profile is read on any login as far as I know. The solution I tend to use is have a .profile which just has a shbang and then sources the .bashrc which holds the env variables I need

Comment: Depending on your image though you may already have something like .bash_profile which sources your .bashrc, it's default on quite a few images / distros

Comment: Thanks for you comments, I will keep that in mind. FYI I use FROM python:3.6-stretch. As it works for now I will use that solution. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables aren't available when you exec because they aren't part of the same execution. You're branching the process off not attaching. What I'd do is create a file `profile` which contains the environment variables you need. Copy it to the root (or whatever user you're executing things with) home directory as `.profile` and you should be good to go.